# Probability of a probability given statistical results

Tags: probability, statistics

Let's say I have a bag of red and blue marbles, but I don't know the distribution of each. I take $10$ marbles from the bag, one at a time, then putting it back, and I get $7$ blue, and $3$ red. What can I say about the distribution of marbles in the bag? What is the probability that there are $\frac{7}{10}$ blue and $\frac{3}{10}$ red, it doesn't have to be that way. What is the probability that the probability of getting a blue is $\frac{7}{10}$, or $\frac{1}{2}$, or any other amount? How would I even start thinking about this? Is there a general way to count it?

EDIT: As pointed out in tommik's answer, the probability of any of these is zero, as there are infinitely many possible probabilities, and the function if them is continuous. However, what if I knew for sure that there were less than $100$ marbles in the bag? I know I could just get a computer to calculate the probability of $7$ blue from each possible set of marbles, then see which one was most likely, but is there an elegant mathematical way?

Comment: Have you heard of maximum likelihood estimators?

Comment: No, what are they?

Comment: Let $X\sim \text{Binomial}(10,p)$ where $p$ represents the true proportion of *blue* marbles in the bag. Define a function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow [0,1]$ by $$f(x)=P(X=7|p=x)$$ The MLE of $p$ is an $x-$value that maximizes $f$. Note $f(x)={10 \choose 7} x^7(1-x)^3$ which is maximized when $x=7/10$. This is your MLE of $p$. Basically, the MLE of $p$ the value of $x$ that maximizes the probability of the event you witnessed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the observed likelihood: 7 Blue and 3 Red, the distribution is the following

$$\pi(\theta|\mathbf{x})\propto \theta^7(1-\theta)^3\cdot\mathbb{1}_{(0;1)}(\theta)$$

which is a Beta distribution

$$(\theta|\mathbf{x})\sim\text{Beta}(8;4)$$

with density

$$f(\theta|\mathbf{x})=1320\cdot\theta^7(1-\theta)^3\cdot\mathbb{1}_{(0;1)}(\theta)$$

Being the distribution absolutely continuous

> the probability that the probability of getting a blue is 7/10, or 1/2, or any other amount

is zero